# How to execute an if line more than once until a certain condition is met

Tags: java, loops

I have a string that has multiple spaces in its beginning.

```
String str = "  new york city";
```

I want only the spaces before the first character to be deleted so a replaceAll would not work.

I have this line of code

```
 if (str.startsWith(" ")){
  str = str.replaceFirst(" ", "");          }
```

This deletes a space but not all. So I need this line to be executed until

```
!str=startswith(" "))
```

I think this can be achieved through a loop but I am VERY unfamiliar with loops. How can I do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `while` or `do ... while`.  You need to be familiar with both if you intend to do any sort of real programming.

Comment: This should do `"  test ".replaceAll("^\\s+", "");`. You can also iterate over a `char[]` with `toCharAray()` and work on the individual characters. There are many answers really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using trim() would remove both starting and ending spaces. But, since you are asking to remove starting spaces, below code might help.

```
public String trimOnlyLeadingSpace()
  {
    int i = this.count;
    int j = 0;
    int k = this.offset;
    char[] arrayOfChar = this.value;
    while ((j < i) && (arrayOfChar[(k + j)] <= ' '))
      ++j;
    return (((j > 0) || (i < this.count)) ? substring(j, i) : this);
  }
```

Comment: What is `count` and `offset`? Looks like you wrote this method to be put in the `String` class itself, which makes no sense.

Comment: Not sure that implementation makes a lot of sense (trim is definitely the way to go though). There is no indication of what `this` is, and therefore no idea what `this.count` and `this.offset` and `this.value` mean... I take it from the coding style that Java might not be the primary language of the writer.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this:

```
s.replaceAll("^\\s+", ""); // will match and replace leading white space
```

Answer (score 2):

[`replaceFirst`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) takes a regular expression, so you want

```
str = str.replaceFirst("\\s+", "");
```

Simple as pie.

Comment: Not correct if there is no leading space. `"new york city".replaceFirst("\\s+", "") == "newyork city"`

Comment: @iamnotmaynard *"I have a string that has multiple spaces in its beginning."*

Comment: ... yeah, ok, assuming he checks for leading space first, this is a good solution. Downvote retracted.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
//str before trim = "    new your city"
str = str.trim();
//str after = "new york city"
```

Comment: OP: "I want only the spaces before the first character to be deleted ..."

Comment: @AndyThomas I'm sure what he meant is that he doesn't want to replace the white spaces between the words.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the `if` to a `while`:

```
 while (str.startsWith(" ")){
    str = str.replaceFirst(" ", "");
```

Another option is to use Guava's `CharMatcher`, which supports trimming only the beginning, or only the end.

```
 str = CharMatcher.is( ' ' ).trimLeadingFrom( str );
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search brought up a page with a simple overview of the two basic loops, while and do-while:

http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/while_loops.html

In your case, you want to use a "while" type of loop, because you want to check the condition before you enter the loop. So it would look something like this:

```
while (str.startsWith(" ")){
  str = str.replaceFirst(" ", "");
}
```

You should be sure to test this code with a string like " " (just a blank space) and "" (empty string), because I'm not entirely sure how startsWith() behaves when the input string is empty.

Learning loops is going to be pretty essential - at least, if your plans involve more than just get through a programming class that you didn't really want to take. (And if you think "while" loops are complicated, wait until you meet "for"!)